# Could not integrate elegant number picker library

Tags: android, gradle

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4136

not able to integrate this library

Stuck with this error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/os/BuildCompat;

here's my gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "matrixdev.com.waitel"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
compile 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
compile('com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0') {
    force = true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the parenthesis for the last compile? like so:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
```

instead of:

```
    compile('com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0')
```